# Obtener y cambiar CSS de algunos contenedores

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, funciones

espero que estén bien, les cuento lo que debo hacer...

Debo hacer una función que me detecte si uno o muchos div dentro de sus estilos tienen la propiedad `background-color: #ffffff;` y en caso de que la tengan, cambiarla por `background-color: #000000;` no se me ocurre alguna forma de poder hacerlo y esta función debe ser aplicada a todo el HTML.

Conocen alguna forma o me podrían ubicar sobre como hacerlo.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En JQuery con el metodo `css()` puedes recuperar las propiedades de estilo que necesitas de un elemento, por ejemplo:

> Actualización:

Dentro de la función click, debes filtrar los div para condicionar utilizando el query $(this) y así poder seleccionar solo los que cumplan con la condición:

```js
//Añado boton para que aprecies el cambio.

  $(".c").click(function(e){  
    $("div").filter(function(){
      var divColor = $(this).css("background-color");
      if (divColor === "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {

      $(this).css({"background-color": "blue"});

    }
    });  
  });
```

```css
.hola, .ala {

  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);

}

.eje {

  background-color: purple;

}

.sys {

  background-color: #FF3;

}

div {

  margin: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hola"></div>
<div class="eje"></div>
<div class="ala"></div>
<div class="sys"></div>
<button class="c">Cambiar color</button>
```

De esta manera puedes ver si algún `div` contiene el color que necesitas cambiar y como ves, solo los que son rojos van a cambiar.

Recuerda expresar los valores de los colores en RGB porque la propiedad css de JQuery siempre los va a devolver así, esto quiere decir que si tienes un `color: red;` JQuery va a retornar `rgb(255, 0, 0)`, si tienes tu color en HEX o solo en CSS, asegúrate de convertir el mismo a RGB para condicionarlo, ejemplo:

```
if (divColor === "rgb(255, 0, 0)"){...} //Si tu color era red, por ejemplo.
//Si no estas seguro igual puedes hacer esto:
if (divColor === "rgb(255, 0, 0)" || divColor === "red"){...}
```

Espero sea de ayuda, un saludo!.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo por tu respuesta, el problema radica en que es para todos los div's que tenga la pagina en el momento, este me funciona solo si es uno

Comment: Funciona en todos amigo! como ves, estoy utilizando la etiqueta div, de todas maneras, déjame actualizar.

Comment: Actualizado! Puedes revisar el código.

Comment: Amigo, listo, ya lo entendí mucho mejor, Muchas gracias